# VSCommands for Visual Studio 2012 keeps saying it is too old

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I've been using VSCommands for several years, and been happy with it until yesterday.

[image]

Now I get this message every time I start Visual Studio. I do have the latest version (11.3.0.5) installed, and if I try to upgrade it the VSIX installer just says I already have it installed. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling VSCommands, but that didn't help.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, well I did take a look at the vendor's support web site https://getsatisfaction.com/dpstudio. 11 questions have been posted over the last 5 months, and zero of them have gotten any reply. But you're right, of course - I'll try sending an email.

Comment: Came here to ask exactly the same, also after checking that forum which seems pretty dead. Nice that it's fixed in such timely manner.

Answer (score 3):

My apologies, this was not really a question for SO. The author responded seven hours after I sent him an email (on a Saturday!):

> Hi!
>
> Thank you for letting me know about this issue, I believe that it
>   should be fixed in latest update (just published).
>
> Kind Regards, Jarek Kardas

The program is now updated to version 11.3.0.9 and is working again.